# Hooking Function Constructor (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hook, v8

Does anyone know of a way to detect when a new function is created?

I know you can hook the function class constructor but that will only detect `new Function()` calls, not `function func(){}` declarations.

I assume the JS engine just creates a default function class when it sees a function declaration instead of looking at the global Function class.

Does anyone know if this is the case or if you can intercept function declarations.

Example function to hook :

```
function add(x,y){return x+y}
```

A hook should get the function when it is defined and hopefully redefine it to be able to capture the arguments, this, and return value.

Comment: What are you trying to do, what do you need this for? What environment do you target?

Comment: I’m trying to identify when new functions are created and hook them to capture their arguments, return value, and this value. I am in the browser. And the need is game hacking.

Comment: declarations can't be "hooked".

Comment: @TDStuart If you want to do this for yourselves, you can probably hook into this with the devtools - look at the profiler or debugger breakpoints for example. But you cannot do it from the code under examination.

Comment: @Jaromanda is there documentation proving this? You can hook direct function class calls. Does a function declaration use a non public function class?

Comment: @Bergi As far as I know you can not hook function declarations even with dev tools.

Comment: @TDStuart - is there documentation disproving it?

Comment: @TDStuart No, you cannot write code that runs when functions are created to replace them with different function indeed - that would be quite complicated. But the hook to capture arguments when a function is called, or result when it returns, already exists - it's called a breakpoint, and you can use them to capture the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

No, there is no way to intercept all function declarations.

FWIW, this isn't up to individual engines to decide; the JavaScript language provides no way to accomplish this, and engines aim to implement the language without any custom deviations (i.e. neither adding nor removing features).

I can offer two alternative ideas that may or may not serve your purposes:
(1) V8 has a `--trace` flag which logs all function entries and returns to stdout. Be warned: this tends to produce a *lot* of output.
(2) You could feed the source of the app you are interested in to a JavaScript parser, and then run whatever analysis (and/or transformation) you want over the AST it produces. This won't catch dynamically generated and `eval`-ed functions, but it will find all `function func() {...}` declarations.

---

> The need is game hacking.

In the interest of helping you ask better questions (so that you may get more helpful answers), I'd like to point out that that's not the level of detail that @Bergi was asking for: the general area in which you are active does not provide any hints for possible alternative approaches. Wanting to hook function declarations so that you can capture their arguments and return values is a search for a specific solution. @Bergi's question is: what is the specific problem that you are trying to solve by intercepting all functions?

That said, "game hacking", while being very vague, does sound sufficiently shady that I'd like to humbly suggest that you not only think about whether you *could*, but alse give sufficient thought to whether you *should*.

Comment: Yes you are right I didn’t give enough detail. I am looking at intercepting functions at runtime with pure JavaScript (no developer tools). The purpose of this is side single player game hacking. There is this extension called tampermonky that allows you to inject JavaScript into a webpage. The goal is the use that JavaScript code to access all functions and variables no matter the scope. You can usually exploit global functions and hook them then backtrace using arguments.callee.caller. Since the Function class is global I was wondering if there was any way to get all function declarations.

Comment: The environment is in the web browser. JavaScript code can be injected before other scripts load. Goal is to use only plain JavaScript code. Once I hooked the function constructor and it didn’t seem to work for normally declared functions (function func(){}) I figured the JavaScript engine had a private function class it uses (probably not even js just the engine doing its magic). But I figured I would ask. If this information still comes by the same result that there is no way to do this or get anywhere close to then I’ll go ahead and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Indeed, there is still no way to intercept all function declarations in JavaScript.